# Upload mime types for ai illustrator file

Tags: uploads

Maybe this topic needs updating because i have certainly used this in the past, but today adobe illustrator ai files are not uploading.

So I'm using [gravity forms plugin](https://docs.gravityforms.com/security/#file-upload-security) to upload my files.

When I tried to initially uploading these file formats...

1. PSD
2. EPS
3. AI
4. SVG

I was getting this message: **Sorry, this file extension is not permitted for security reasons** for all of these file formats.

So I filtered my upload mimes by adding this function to my class...

```
/**
 * my class constructor
*/
public function __construct()
{

    // allow extra mime type uploads
    add_filter( 'upload_mimes' , array ($this, 'custom_upload_mimes'));

}

/**
 * Allow extra mime types for the sample upload
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = [] )
{

    $existing_mimes['psd']  = 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop';
    $existing_mimes['eps']  = 'application/postscript';
    $existing_mimes['ai']   = 'application/postscript';
    $existing_mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';

    return $existing_mimes;

}
```

After a bit of testing, all those file types listed above uploaded fine... apart from the illustrator file.

I removed this function and I was not able to upload any of these formats. I re-invoked the function and again, only the illustrator `.ai` file was returning the error message.

I also tried a very old illustrator file to see if was a file issue but the result was the same.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$mime_types[ 'eps' ] = 'application/postscript';
$mime_types[ 'ai'  ] = 'application/pdf';
$mime_types[ 'svg' ] = 'image/svg+xml';`
```

and then return `$mime_types`

Comment: Thank you let me check soon, i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

im putting this info here (not about upload) but according to [adobe docs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/assets/administer/assets-formats.html?lang=en#supported-mime-types) the mime types list as following

for `.ai` is `application/postscript`

for `eps` can be any of the following EPS

1. `application/postscript`
2. `application/eps`
3. `application/x-eps`
4. `image/eps`
5. `image/x-eps`

for `psd` is `image/vnd.adobe.photoshop`

for `svg` is `image/svg+xml`